# Make a trigger stop inserting same data on different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created three tables, as shown below, and I want to create a trigger such that when I try to insert a new record into `table_2` while that record is already in `table_3`, an error message is shown and the insertion of duplicated data is prevented. This should also work the other way around, the same data can not be present in both tables.

```
create table table_1 (
  a varchar(255),
  b integer,
  d varchar(255),
  primary key(a, b)
);

create table table_2 (
  a varchar(255),
  b integer,
  c varchar(255),
  primary key(a, b, c),
  foreign key(a, b) references table_1(a, b)
);

create table table_3 (
  a varchar(255),
  b integer,
  c varchar(255),
  primary key(a, b, c),
  foreign key(a, b) references table_1(a, b)
);
```

Comment: why do you need two tables with the same structure? Can't you use a single table with a column called `type`?

Comment: No, it must be like this because the population on table_1 mus be divided and be in table_2 or table_3 but not both

Comment: How does `table_1` fit into this picture? It is not clearly explained in your question. Please try to rephrase it (you can edit your original question) to make it more clear.

Comment: @cha's suggestion is good.  I can't think of a reason why you need to keep data with the same format in 2 different tables.  Please give an example of a query or other operation that would not be able to run if all the rows exist in a single table with a `type` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid inserting same data in two different tables you need to test whether the data is already in the other table when inserting. Note that you should also do this test when updating records in either of the two tables. You can do both actions, in both directions, with a single trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_duplicates_in_tables_2_3() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  -- Check if the new data is in either of the two tables, works for inserts and updates
  PERFORM * FROM table_2 WHERE a = NEW.a AND b = NEW.b AND c = NEW.c;
  IF FOUND THEN
    RAISE 'Data is already present in table_2';
  END IF;
  PERFORM * FROM table_3 WHERE a = NEW.a AND b = NEW.b AND c = NEW.c;
  IF FOUND THEN
    RAISE 'Data is already present in table_3';
  END IF;

  -- Data is unique so let the insert or update operation succeed.
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For each of the two tables you should define a trigger that calls the trigger function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER table_2_duplicate_check
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table_2
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_duplicates_in_tables_2_3();

CREATE TRIGGER table_3_duplicate_check
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table_3
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_duplicates_in_tables_2_3();
```

Note that the trigger function would greatly benefit from the presence of indexes on table_2 and table_3.

Comment: Sorry but answer does not solve my problem. The function doesn't work. When I insert new data it always shows the error message I don't think the function is checking if the data inserted on table_2 is already on table_3. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You are right. The function is alright, but the trigger has to fire before the operation. So in the `CREATE TRIGGER` command, replace the keyword `AFTER` with `BEFORE`. In either case, if an answer does not work you should say so, giving a description of the failure. Only like that can the community on SO provide you with a working answer.

Comment: Happy to have helped you @user3613231! With triggers in general, you fire them `BEFORE` if you want to modify what data gets inserted/updated or to cancel the operation (as in your case); you fire a trigger `AFTER` if you want to have some side-effect from the operation, such as posting a message in an audit table.